# How to access spring configuration XML file from another project?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to Access Bean.xml in SpringPrgramm2 whereas Beans.xml is present in the SpringProgramm1 project. Both are java project.

Please find my code below :

SpringProramm1 java project in Eclipse :
(only Beans.xml is present in src folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <bean id="textEditor" class="com.surajhome.practice.spring.TextEditor">
        <property name="spellChecker">  
        <bean id="spellChecker" class="com.surajhome.practice.spring.SpellChecker"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

SpringPrgoramm 2 java project :

1. MainApp.java
2. SpellChecker.java
3. TextEditor.java

MainApp.java code below which is failing to access beans.xml from another java project.

```
package com.surajhome.practice.spring;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

    public class MainApp {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            ApplicationContext appContext=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:SpringProgram1/Beans.xml");     
            TextEditor obj1 = (TextEditor) appContext.getBean("textEditor");
            obj1.spellCheck();

        }
    }
```

How can we access this Beans.xml file in the SpringProgramm2 project?

Exception :

```
Apr 21, 2018 7:17:24 PM org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@694f9431: startup date [Sat Apr 21 19:17:24 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 21, 2018 7:17:24 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [SpringProgram1/Beans.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [SpringProgram1/Beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [SpringProgram1/Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:258)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:621)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.surajhome.practice.spring.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:11)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [SpringProgram1/Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe that the structure of your projects is not cohesive. It does not make sense for the classes in your SpringProgramm2 project to be configured in the SpringProgramm1 project XML, as these classes belong to the SpringProgramm2 project.
So, I gave an example of how your projects would be more cohesive using Maven:

1. Your new [SpringProgramm1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65ZfO.png) project.
2. Your new [SpringProgramm2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyqwa.png) project:

In my example, your SpringProgramm2 would depend on SpringProgramm1:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>br.edu.claudivan</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringPrgramm1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

In SpringProgramm1, you can keep the configuration of your beans. In SpringProgramm2, you keep the MainApp.java class to load the context XML that would look like this:

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/Beans.xml");
        TextEditor obj1 = (TextEditor) context.getBean("textEditor");
        obj1.spellChecker();
    }
}
```

I put the example code on [my github](https://github.com/claudivanmoreira/stack-overflow/tree/master/spring-question01).

Hope this helps!